# Customer parameter are not going through for file delete

Tags: javascript, jquery, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

I have setup to directly upload image to s3 bucket and I am using fine uploader for that.

I am trying to send filename as parameter (to end point) while deleting a file.

Given below is callback snippet .

```
onDelete: function(id) {
    $(this).setDeleteFileParams({ filename: this.getName(id) });
}
```

It is working fine for newly uploaded files, but I already have files through `initialList` (Option) and when I try to delete them the `filename` param is not going through.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the jQuery wrapper correctly. This is one of many reasons why [I have suggested avoiding jQuery and the jQuery wrapper](https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/1310), as the "vanilla" API is much more intuitive. You've left out some code, but it looks like you are actually declaring your event handler as a property of the `callbacks` config object, which means you can avoid the jQuery wrapper entirely.

```
onDelete: function(id) {
    var name = this.getName(id);
    this.setDeleteFileParams({filename: name}, id);
}
```

But this code is not necessary, as [Fine Uploader S3 sends the name of the object in S3 as a "key" parameter with the delete request](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/endpoint_handlers/amazon-s3.html#delete-file-feature-support-optional).