# setDeleteFileParams doesnt seem to work

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

I am using 5.3.2 in basic mode as I need control over the UI.

I have added code to allow the uploads and then created little UI elements that can then trigger a deletion. I need to know the filename when I am deleting. So I used setDeleteFileParams but nothing is attached to the request.

```
var uploader = new qq.FineUploaderBasic({

button: document.getElementById('btnUploadFiles'),
debug: true,
autoUpload: true,

request: {
paramsInBody: true,
endpoint: '../myendpoint.htm',
params: {
    tempID: 'myidwhatever'
    }
},
deleteFile: {
    enabled: true,
    forceConfirm: false,
    method: 'POST',
    endpoint: '../myendpoint.htm'

},

callbacks: {

    onSubmitted: function(id, name){
        //do work
    },
    onDelete: function(id) {
        this.setDeleteFileParams({filename: this.getName(id)}, id);
    },
    onDeleteComplete: function(UID, xhr, isError){
        //remove my UI element
    },



    onComplete: function(UID, name, responseJSON, xhr) {
        //create an element and stick it in


    }

}


})
//ADD THE DELETE BUTTON ACTIONS

$('uploadedFiles').addEvent("click:relay(.deleteMyFile)", function(event, element) {
    event.preventDefault();
    arr = element.id.split('_')
    uploader.deleteFile(arr[1]);
});
```

Im using Mootools as my JS framework. Everything triggers ok and the console logs out the filename correctly when I delete a file but when I look at the request there is no 'filename' parameter.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the time your `onDeleteFile` callback has been called, the file is already setup to be deleted. If you'd like to influence (or prevent) the underlying request, you'll need to put your logic inside of a [`onSubmitDelete` callback handler instead](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#submitDelete).

For example:

```
callbacks: {
    onSubmitDelete: function(id) {
        console.log(this.getName(id));
        this.setDeleteFileParams({filename: this.getName(id)}, id);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for that, makes perfect sense and it works great. I was following the example (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16305517/fineuploader-submitdelete-get-filename-and-extension) there. Might be worth editing that as it definitely doesnt work, perhaps it did in an earlier version.

Comment: @RolfHerbert The example you linked to is functionally equivalent to my answer.

Comment: sorry @Ray-Nicholus my mistake I meant this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31069212/customer-parameter-are-not-going-through-for-file-delete) referring to the the onDelete call back there.